# why is bootstrap 5 Carousel not working even thought i copied the code from their website

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-carousel

So i am making a webpage with bootstrap 5, I am using the CDN to work with it.
I want to use their carousel but it doesn't seem to work. I haven't made any changes to their code other than changing the image "src". I have copied it from their website.
The following is a part of my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]>      <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Alpha Ace Trading</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-white fixed-top ">
            <div class="container">
                <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Alpha Ace</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navmenu"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navmenu">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link">home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link">home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link">home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link">home</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <section class="bg-grey text-dark text-center p-3 p-md-5">
            <div class="container text-center text-md-start">
                <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-around my-5 g-4 w-100 mx-auto">
                    <div class="col-md-6 order-2 order-md-1">
                        <h1>hello world</h1>
                        <p class="lead">hi himnish please put some content here thank you</p>
                        <p class="lead">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae ab mollitia, nobis impedit ipsa porro.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-5 order-1 text-center order-md-2">
                        <img class="rounded-max shadow img-fluid w-100" src="assets/dummy-picture.jpeg" alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-around my-5 g-4 w-100 mx-auto">
                    <div class="col-md-6 order-2 p-4">
                        <h1>hello world</h1>
                        <p class="lead">hi himnish please put some content here thank you</p>
                        <p class="lead">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae ab mollitia, nobis impedit ipsa porro.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-5 order-1 text-center">
                        <img class="rounded-max shadow img-fluid w-100" src="assets/dummy-picture.jpeg" alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <!-- text on image -->
        <section class="bg-dark text-light">
            <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                </ol>
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                  <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img class="d-block w-50 mx-auto" src="assets/bse.svg" alt="First slide">
                  </div>
                  <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="d-block w-50 mx-auto" src="assets/bitcoin.png" alt="Second slide">
                  </div>
                  <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="d-block w-50 mx-auto" src="assets/nse.png" alt="Third slide">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                  <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                  <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
              </div>
        </section>
        <!--[if lt IE 7]>
            <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="#">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="" async defer></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

the result that I am getting is the following

[image]

as you can see the indicators aren't showing and nor do the buttons work when I click on them

Comment: Check your browser console. Do you see any error messages?

Comment: no I don't get any error message, neither on loading the page not on click the buttons.

Comment: do you have the style.css stylesheet in the same folder?

Comment: yes I do have a style.css but I haven't added any classes to that section not to any thing related to Bootstrap 5

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work here: (when you prefix bootstrap attributes with `data-bs-something`). I've also matched the version of the js with that of the css. It seemed to solve an error message appearing after last slide.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]>      <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Alpha Ace Trading</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-white fixed-top ">
    <div class="container">
      <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Alpha Ace</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navmenu"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navmenu">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">home</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <section class="bg-grey text-dark text-center p-3 p-md-5">
    <div class="container text-center text-md-start">
      <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-around my-5 g-4 w-100 mx-auto">
        <div class="col-md-6 order-2 order-md-1">
          <h1>hello world</h1>
          <p class="lead">hi himnish please put some content here thank you</p>
          <p class="lead">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae ab mollitia, nobis impedit ipsa porro.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5 order-1 text-center order-md-2">
          <img class="rounded-max shadow img-fluid w-100" src="assets/dummy-picture.jpeg" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-around my-5 g-4 w-100 mx-auto">
        <div class="col-md-6 order-2 p-4">
          <h1>hello world</h1>
          <p class="lead">hi himnish please put some content here thank you</p>
          <p class="lead">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae ab mollitia, nobis impedit ipsa porro.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5 order-1 text-center">
          <img class="rounded-max shadow img-fluid w-100" src="assets/dummy-picture.jpeg" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- text on image -->
  <section class="bg-dark text-light">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img class="d-block w-50 mx-auto" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1000/200" alt="First slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block w-50 mx-auto" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1001/200" alt="Second slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block w-50 mx-auto" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1002/200" alt="Third slide">
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-bs-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-bs-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!--[if lt IE 7]>
            <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="#">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```